# maven release plugin and multiple inter dependent libs (multiple gits) - what is the correct way to structure?

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a set of libraries, that each have their own git repository, and they are inter-dependent.

I have a problem in updating the versions automatically and tagging the git repo in such a way
to maintain dependencies. Doing this manually(editing 26 files) would be tedious as there are many libraries (26).

*Is there perhaps a pattern that solves this problem (HOWTO)?*

**This is my solution that is failing:**

Currently I have one parent pom and was thinking that the release plugin would solve this,
but this seems to be problematic with multiple git repos.

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DdevelopmentVersion=1.3-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=1.2
```

...

```
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/wayne/Documents && git commit --verbose -F /tmp/maven-scm-967028403.commit pom.xml utils/pom.xml streams/pom.xml
[INFO] Working directory: /home/wayne/Documents
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parent library .................................... FAILURE [11.694s]
[INFO] utils    .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] streams ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.015s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 21 12:49:20 CAT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project libparent: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-commit command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] error: pathspec 'utils/pom.xml' did not match any file(s) known to git.
[ERROR] error: pathspec 'streams/pom.xml' did not match any file(s) known to git.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

My directory structure is as such:

```
/home/wayne/Documents/ (libparent module,the root pom is in here ans has a git repo)
/home/wayne/Documents/utils (this is a separate git repo)
/home/wayne/Documents/stream (this is also a separate git repo)
```

And my POM Files:libparent

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
  <artifactId>libparent</artifactId>
  <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>parent library</name>
  <description>A parent pom for all library modules</description>

    <modules>
            <module>utils</module>
            <module>streams</module>
    </modules>

              <scm>
                    <url>https://server.xyz.co.za/repos/code/javacode/libraries/${project.artifactId}</url>
                    <connection>scm:git:ssh://user@server.xyz.co.za/git/javacode/libraries/${project.artifactId}</connection>
                    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://user@server.xyz.co.za/git/javacode/libraries/${project.artifactId}</developerConnection>
                    <tag>HEAD</tag>
            </scm>



 <build>

                <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.5</version>
                                 <executions>
                                        <execution>
                                        <id>default</id>
                                        <goals>
                                                <goal>perform</goal>
                                        </goals>

                                        <configuration>
                                        <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                                        <goals>deploy</goals>
                                        <autoversionsubmodules>true</autoversionsubmodules>
                                        <commitByProject>true</commitByProject>
                                        <!--
                                        <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
                                        -->
                                        <!--
                                        <checkModificationExcludes>
                                                <checkModificationExclude>pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
                                        </checkModificationExcludes>
                                        -->
                                        <!--    
                                        <dependencies>
                                                <dependency>
                                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                                                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                                                        <version>1.8.1</version>
                                                </dependency>

                                                <dependency>
                                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                                                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-git-commons</artifactId>
                                                        <version>1.8.1</version>
                                                </dependency>       
                                        </dependencies>
                                        -->
                                </configuration>
                                 </execution>
                                 </executions>
                        </plugin>
```

Pom for the utils library:

```
<project ....>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <parent>
                <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
                <artifactId>libparent</artifactId>
                <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>


        <scm>
                <url>https://server.xyz.co.za/repos/code/javacode/libraries/${project.artifactId}</url>
                <connection>scm:git:ssh://user@server.xyz.co.za/git/javacode/libraries/${project.artifactId}</connection>
                <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://user@server.xyz.co.za/git/javacode/libraries/${project.artifactId}</developerConnection>
                <tag>HEAD</tag>
        </scm>
</project>
```

Pom for the streams library:

```
<project ...>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <artifactId>streams</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <parent>
                <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
                <artifactId>libparent</artifactId>
                <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>

             <scm>
                    <url>https://server.xyz.co.za/repos/code/javacode/libraries/${project.artifactId}</url>
                    <connection>scm:git:ssh://user@server.xyz.co.za/git/javacode/libraries/${project.artifactId}</connection>
                    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://user@server.xyz.co.za/git/javacode/libraries/${project.artifactId}</developerConnection>
                    <tag>HEAD</tag>
            </scm>


        <dependencies>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <classifier>mobile</classifier>
                        <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>

        </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: Not your answer but something that looks odd: Your command line includes: "-DdevelopmentVersion=1.3-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=1.2" Shouldn't the release version be 1.3?

Comment: If you have mulit module build those module plus the appropriate parent should be in the same repository. If you would like to release them together it would make more sense. Apart from that with Maven-release-plugin this is not supported.